# Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно использовать легкое для создания справочника

Tags: java, android, html, xml, webview

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно использовать легкое для создания справочника к примеру (библиотеки или методы), сейчас использую веб вейв для открытия локальных html. Нужно Что-нибудь полегче можно к примеру открывать xml файлы ? 
К примеру можно открыть xml из assets в виде текста с разметкой
веб грузит долго и некрасиво это выглядит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite можно попробовать для хранения данных на андройде.
В форму отображения будете подгружать данные из базы, без лишних движений.

Comment: нет вы наверно не поняли или я, мне нужно отображать кон тент то есть как листы вроде каждый разный на одном таблица на другом с изображениями текст и тд. А для каждого из листов нужна разметка, а их(листов) сотни

Comment: А. Каталог шаблонов получается. Простите, я не понял сразу. Но решение в принципе выглядит аналогичным: берём базовый шаблон-контейнер. В него подгружаем шаблон из БД, куда транслируем необходимые данные, из той же базы или определяемые пользователем.

Т.е. в базе есть таблица с шаблонами, содержащая поля "id","template". Поле "template" - типа Text или Varchar. В него сохраняем шаблоны.

В приложении имеем базовый шаблон со структурой (грубо) `<body><div id="container"></div></body>` - где в элементе #container заменяем innerHtml на подгружаемые шаблоны из БД.

Comment: да я тут нашел XMLReader у андроида есть, только статей про него чтото немного нашел, вроде неплохое решение а данные через json могу получать. Или это не лучший вариант?

Comment: 1. Откуда и какие данные будет считывать XMLReader? (Какой XML будет парсить и во что превращать? Зачем он будет это делать?). 2. Какие данные должны быть обращены в JSON и для передачи куда?

Если Вы планируете хранить разметку страницы (html или xml шаблон) в базе, то я правильно понял, что JSON данные Вы будете применять для наполнения этих шаблонов после выгрузки их в шаблон-контейнер? Если так, то схема должна работать.